# What does "tea juice" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I heard in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2FHv1CcBJ_k?t=511) this line:

> We could say for a vegan it's bad to drink milk. But a non-vegan who doesn't abide by that moral code will drink all the **tea juice** they want. ([source](https://youtu.be/2FHv1CcBJ_k?t=511))

It seems "tea/T juice" here refers to milk, but what does it mean exactly? Why is milk called "tea/T juice"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think he's humorously referring to milk as "teat juice" (not "tea juice") because it is squeezed from a cow's teats (i.e., udders).

Comment: I didn't believe it, but checking the video, that's what he said.

Comment: Somewhat unsurprisingly, there is an [entry in Urban Dictionary for "Bovine Teat Juice"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bovine%20Teat%20Juice)

Comment: Also known as "baby cow growth hormone".